# lcov marking lines with function declarations as reachable but not covered

Tags: c++, clang, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

I'm trying to use lcov (v1.13, on OS X, with clang as compiler) to generate code coverage for my test suite and I've hit one annoying problem that I don't know how to solve. There's a few similar questions on SO, but I couldn't find the solution to this one. For some reason, function/member declarations are marked as reachable but not executed, kind of like in the example below (this is inline method definition in a header):

[image]

This renders line coverage metrics useless, so I was hoping there's a way to fix it without marking each declaration as LCOV_EXCL_LINE.

Compiler flags used are pretty standard:

```
-g -O0 -fno-inline -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs -fno-elide-constructors
```

What's strange is that method *definitions* in source files are also marked as red, although the bodies are not, e.g.:

```
// header.h
class Foo { 
    void bar();      // ignored, marked as unreachable
}  

// header.cpp
void Foo::bar() {    // marked as red (reachable / not executed)
    do_something();  // marked as covered
}
```

If it's of any importance, the source files are part of a static library that's statically linked to the test harness in CMake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Apparently, `lcov -i` (initial capture) assumes that starting lines of functions are instrumented, whereas with LLVM they are actually not (whereas with GCC where they are). There is an upstream GitHub issue ([linux-test-project/lcov#30](https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov/issues/30)) documenting this in more detail.

Until this is fixed upstream in `lcov`, I've posted a simple [workaround](https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov/issues/30#issuecomment-353799085) -- a Python script that removes function starting lines from base coverage file, which should "fix" it, at least temporarily.